# TypeScript - difference between import ... and import {...} (with curly braces)

Tags: typescript, import

Coming from Java to TS, I've omitted the `{...}` around the imported type.

```
import DiscriminatorMappingData from './DiscriminatorMappingData';
```

instead of

```
import {DiscriminatorMappingData} from './DiscriminatorMappingData';
```

See [TypeScript - storing a class as a map value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715797/typescript-storing-a-class-as-a-map-value?noredirect=1#comment64813552_38715797).

I've read the documentation and didn't understand much. I only took from it that when I only need one type from a file, I can omit the `{}`.
However, that caused weird errors, like "Unknown name", or unexpected type incompatibilites.

So, what's the difference, put simply?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The difference between your two `import` declarations is covered in the TypeScript specification. From §11.3.2, [Import Declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#11.3.2):

> An import declaration of the form
>
> `import d from "mod";`
>
> is exactly equivalent to the import declaration
>
> `import { default as d } from "mod";`

Thus, you would omit the braces *only* when you are importing something that was exported as the `default` entity of the module (with an `export default` declaration, of which there can only be one per module). The name you provide in the `import` declaration becomes an alias for that imported entity.

When importing anything else, even if it's just one entity, you need to provide the braces.

Answer (score 32):

The `default` import needs to be without curly braces. It's easy to understand with the following example of the calculator functions.

```
// Calculator.ts

export default function plus() { }    // Default export 

export function minus() { }           // Named export

export function multiply() { }        // Named export
```

---

### Default Import: No Curly Braces

```
// CalculatorTest.ts

import plus from "./Calculator"
```

The `plus` should not be enclosed with the curly braces because it is exported using the `default` keyword.

---

### Named Import: With Curly Braces

```
// CalculatorTest.ts

import plus, { minus, multiply } from "./Calculator"
```

The `minus` and `multiply` should be inside the curly braces because they are exported using only the `export` keyword. Note that the `plus` is outside of the curly braces.

---

### Alias for Default Import

If you want an alias for the `default` import, you can do it with/without curly braces:

```
// CalculatorTest.ts

import { default as add, minus, multiply } from "./Calculator"
```

OR

```
// CalculatorTest.ts

import add, { minus, multiply} from './Calculator'
```

Now the `plus()` function becomes `add()`. This works because only one default export is allowed per module.

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

This is imports in `destructruring` format. Essentially grouping all the entities that we want to be imported `from` a definition file.

If you are familiar with other programming languages you might be familiar with the destructuring notion. Actually `destructuring` was added in the form of [assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as part of `es6`.

Import restructuring support was first suggested in TypeScript in [this Github ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1563) but then got grouped under [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242) that was tracking all the `es6 modules`.