# Different TypeScript import types

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between these TypeScript import types?

```
import SettingsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Settings";
import { MenuList } from "@material-ui/core";
```

As far as I understand, the first one without curly brackets is a direct class import and and the second is one class out of a collection of classes. Would that be right? One thing that does not work is importing several `*Icon` classes from `@material-ui/icons` and I cannot really tell why, i.e. the following does not work:

```
import { ImageIcon, LanguageIcon, DescriptionIcon, MenuIcon, SchoolIcon, SettingsIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

Why can I not import those icon classes? How can I find out what type of import I need?

Comment: Have a look at this page, please. Here they explain how to handle these icons: https://material-ui.com/style/icons/. It is a design decision and somewhat stability too whether you provide each component or icon in a separate path or not. There was a time when everyone was keen using the so called 'barrels' which are index.ts-files which you could use to bundle imports. But due to circle dependency problems they recommended somewhen not to do it anymore. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: This post answers your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729486/typescript-difference-between-import-and-import-with-curly-braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through the document, for imports - it clearly states that

**If your environment doesn't support tree-shaking, the recommended way to import the icons is the following:**

```
 import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
 import ThreeDRotation from '@material-ui/icons/ThreeDRotation';
```

**If your environment support tree-shaking you can also import the icons this way:**

```
 import { AccessAlarm, ThreeDRotation } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

So, you can do it only if your dev environment supports tree-shaking. You can refer to the document here: [Imports for material-ui](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/)