# TypeScript with classic moduleResolution work incorrect

Tags: javascript, typescript

i learn from https://zhongsp.gitbook.io/typescript-handbook/handbook/module-resolution that with **moduleResolution=classic**,

the typescript compiler looking for module in this order

1. /root/src/folder/moduleB.ts
2. /root/src/folder/moduleB.d.ts
3. /root/src/moduleB.ts
4. /root/src/moduleB.d.ts
5. /root/moduleB.ts
6. /root/moduleB.d.ts
7. /moduleB.ts
8. /moduleB.d.ts

but i found that when i use

`import {a} from "a"`

it shows can't find module,

my file structure is

**|--main.ts**

**|--a.ts**

**|--node_modules**

it works only when i put **a.ts** in the folder **node_modules**

is that **moduleResolution=classic** is no longer support anymore or something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As statet in the **[TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)**:

> **Module Resolution Strategy Classic**: This used to be TypeScript’s default resolution strategy. Nowadays, this strategy is mainly present for backward compatibility.

I don't know exactly know how your modules look but I assume you have something like this in your **`a.ts`** file:

```
export default a;
```

if so then you should be able to import your module like this (notice also the path starts with './' for the current folder):

```
import a from "./a"
```

---

but if your **`a.ts`** looks more like this (no export default):

```
export const a....
```

Than you need to import it like this:

```
import { a } from "./a"
```

> Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729486/typescript-difference-between-import-and-import-with-curly-braces) for closer information on module imports

Comment: i know i can import it using relative path,but i don't know why none-relative doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `baseUrl` to your tsconfig.

see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl