# TypeScript - can't retype <typeof FrameModel> window["FrameModel"];

Tags: typescript, casting, window

I have a map of classes extending a class `FrameModel`, see [TypeScript - storing a class as a map value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715797/typescript-storing-a-class-as-a-map-value).

```
static mapping: { [key: string]: typeof FrameModel } = {

for (var key in Object.keys(window)){
    var val = window[key];
    // ... some checks ...
    DiscriminatorMapping.mapping[key] = <typeof FrameModel> val;
}
```

However, TS doesn't like the the last line, saying "error TS2352: Neither type 'Window' nor type 'typeof FrameModel' is assignable to the other."

In `lib.d.ts`, the definition is: `declare var window: Window;`
Why does TS apply this to the properties of `window` too?

I can prevent that with `<any>`, but I was wondering how to do it properly.
 Note that I don't know the name of the property in advance, so I can't do something like `declare window.MyClass: FrameModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration is wrong.

It should either be:

```
for (var key in window) {
    var val = window[key];
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
let keys = Object.keys(window);
for (var i in keys) {
    let key = keys[i];
    let val = window[key];
    ...
}
```

Or using the forEach:

```
Object.keys(window).forEach(key => {
    let val = window[key];
    ...
});
```

The reason you're getting that error is because the [`Window` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L16957) has a lot of named properties and then [at the end](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L17223):

```
interface Window {
    ...
    [index: number]: Window;
}
```

Which means that anything you access to in `Window` using an index is of type `Window`.
To bypass that just cast to `any`:

```
for (var key in window) {
    var val = window[key] as any;
    // ... some checks ...
    DiscriminatorMapping.mapping[key] = <typeof FrameModel> val;
}
```